# node-webkit crashes when I create an ArrayBuffer inside c++ add-on

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node-webkit

I am writing a node-webkit c++ add-on, it crashes every time I try to create an ArrayBuffer. The following code is a minimal crash example.

```
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace v8;

Handle<Value> createVector(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;
  Handle<ArrayBuffer> a = ArrayBuffer::New(12);
  return scope.Close(a);
}

void init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("createVector"),
      FunctionTemplate::New(createVector)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(vectortest, init)
```

Every time I call the createVector() method node-webkit crashes on Windows 8.
I call it from the console using the following javascript code:

```
var m=require('vectortest');
m.createVector();
```

I tried it on node-webkit 0.7.2 and 0.7.5. Any suggestion?

Comment: May be related to this issue https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/issues/199

Comment: I think is a totally different problem here, I'm packaging anything

Comment: Seems that I have to use the ArrayBuffer declared and implemented in v8_typed_array.cc instead of the one declared in v8.h.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I solved my problem using the workaround below.

```
Handle<Object> createBuffer(void *data, size_t size) {
    if (size == 0)
        throw "Zero sized data";
    Handle<Value> abv = Context::GetCurrent()->Global()->Get(String::NewSymbol("ArrayBuffer"));
    Handle<Value> argv[] = { Integer::NewFromUnsigned(size) };
    Handle<Object> arrbuf = Handle<Function>::Cast(abv)->NewInstance(1, argv);
    void *buffer = arrbuf->GetPointerFromInternalField(0);
    memcpy(buffer, data, size);

    Handle<Value> ui8av = Context::GetCurrent()->Global()->Get(String::NewSymbol("Uint8Array"));
    argv[0] = arrbuf;
    Handle<Object> result = Handle<Function>::Cast(ui8av)->NewInstance(1, argv);
    return result;
}
```

Obviously in the v8 namespace.
It seems that node, and in consequence node-webkit, re-implements the ArrayBuffer, TypedArray, Uint8Array and so on in node/src/v8_typed_array.cc. They are totally different from the ones in v8.h and they haven't an header file to include.
Initially I had in my javascript code something like this:

```
var buffer = ... // call function that in the end call createBuffer
var data = new Uint8Array(buffer);
```

and createBuffer was returning the arrbuf ArrayBuffer but I had problems doing that: data length was always 0. Instead, by creating the Uint8Array in c++ code the behavior is right, I don't know why.